# reload rows without calling tableview.reload

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hello in my application i am appending data into array then inserting rows into table view like this

```
 self.table.beginUpdates()
 self.datasource.append(Data)
 self.table.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.datasource.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
 self.table.endUpdates()
```

everything is working fine in this code ,now  when i want to swipe to refresh the all the rows but i don't want to use table.reloadData because it remove all the records and show white screen for a seconds , i want to reload all the rows without using it 
i am trying in this way but it crash the application

```
@objc func handleRefresh(_ refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
        if (datasource.count > 0 ){
            datasource.removeAll() 
             page_num = 1
            get_past_orders(page: page_num)
              self.isLoading =  false
            refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        }
    }
```

application crash on

```
   self.table.endUpdates()
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20)
```

Comment: What do you mean swipe to refresh, i have only seen pull to refresh!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/YsDGnHJa

Comment: yes i am talking about pull to refresh!

Comment: no need to do any thing reload work fin

Comment: i don't want to use reload because it appear white screen for few seconds when orders loads

Comment: it all up to you , if you reload few seconds later than it appears later

Comment: You are calling `datasource.removeAll()` first and then `get_past_orders`on refresh. That would explain why you see a blank page for a while. You shouldn't have to do that. When you insert data to your table, make sure to also add it to your model.

Comment: Use a more sophisticated logic. Rather than removing all items reload the data into a temporary array, then insert and delete only those items which had changed. By the way `begin-/endUpdates` has not effect at all for a single `insert/delete/move` operation.

Answer (score 3):

your approach was right:

you have to also append the new item into your "itemlist"

```
items.append(newItem)

let selectedIndexPath = IndexPath(row: items.count - 1, section: 0)

tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.insertRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

thats all :)

---

**EDIT: Example**

a little example which works perfectly for me:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    struct Item {
        var field_a: String
        var field_b: Bool
        var field_c: Int
    }

    // MARK: - properties
    var items = [Item]()

    // MARK: - object-properties
    let tableView = UITableView()
    let addButton = UIButton()

    // MARK: - system-methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.addSubview(addButton)

        addButton.titleLabel?.text  = "ADD"
        addButton.titleLabel?.textColor = .white
        addButton.backgroundColor   = .blue
        addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleButton), for: .touchUpInside)

        tableView.dataSource  = self

        addButton.anchor(top: nil, leading: nil, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor, padding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 24, right: 24), size: CGSize(width: 84, height: 48))
        tableView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor)

        prepareItems()
    }

    // MARK: - preparation-methods

    func prepareItems() {
        items.append(Item(field_a: "cell1", field_b: false, field_c: 0))
        items.append(Item(field_a: "cell2", field_b: false, field_c: 0))
        items.append(Item(field_a: "cell3", field_b: false, field_c: 0))

    }

    // MARK: - helper-methods

    func appendNewItem(_ item: Item) {
        items.append(item)

        let selectedIndexPath = IndexPath(row: items.count - 1, section: 0)

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.insertRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }

    // MARK: - action-methods

    @objc func handleButton() {
        appendNewItem(Item(field_a: "new Cell", field_b: true, field_c: 0))
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        let currItem = items[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text    = currItem.field_a

        return cell
    }
}
```

---

fyi: .anchor() is a method written by me. - it sets all AutoLayout-Constraints.

Comment: i need to add this after the swipe refresh or every time?

Comment: you have to do this every time you get new data. In your logic I think you have to call it after the completion of your swipe refresh.

Comment: just fyi, the `.insertRows` just updates all cells with the indexpaths which you forward in the first parameter of `insertRows`

Comment: @Shahzad: "it does not work" is not very useful to be able to help you. Please indicate what part is not working.

Comment: `begin-/endUpdates` has not effect at all for a single `insert/delete/move` operation

Answer (score 1):

Using Objective-C:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPathOfYourCell, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: it work for me but i don't know why it makes me a problem for pagination at the end it refresh again nd again

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload row of a tableView without calling tableView's reload method each and every time.
You can use

```
self.itemTableView.reloadRows(at: [NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0) as IndexPath], with: .automatic)
```

you can insert desired IndexPath value (You want to reload) at the place of

```
[NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0) as IndexPath]
```

and with: is here type of UITableViewRowAnimation type, you want to reload with animation. It provides many option like .automatic, .bottom, .fade, .middle, .top, .left, .right and .none etc.

These all animation options provide you different ways to reload table row with the different type.

Comment: its crashing still